# Syncopation in classical music

Tags: classical-music, baroque-period, syncopation, classical-period

Can anyone can point me, a lay person, to good examples of syncopation in classical music? I'm also wondering if syncopation shows up at all in Baroque music.

Thank you.

Comment: This question is clearly not about a particular song.  I've voted to reopen it.

Comment: Pergolesi flute concerto in g major https://www.google.com/search?q=pergolesi+flute+concerto+in+g+major+pdf&client=safari&rls=en&source=lnms&tbm=vid&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi8g4rNkZr8AhWziP0HHSRyBBUQ_AUoAXoECAIQAw&biw=1397&bih=715&dpr=2&safari_group=9#fpstate=ive&vld=cid:1d338f8f,vid:W9fY5RmrrKo

Comment: @phoog I think the issue is that it's a "list question," and with our limited supply of canned close-vote reasons, this is the closest fit. I prefer to choose "other" and explicitly mention lists when encountering them. To Rivah: Welcome! You can see more about the topics that are covered [here](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). If you'd like to know more *about* syncopation, besides just names of pieces that show it, I encourage you to edit this question or start a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Try this - Mozart Piano Concerto No.20 in D minor, 1st movement.  https://www.bing.com/videos/search?q=mozart+piano+concerto+number+20+in+d+minor&view=detail&mid=4764F5B7886535F1A57E4764F5B7886535F1A57E&FORM=VIRE

And yes, it's to be found in Baroque Music too, and even earlier. Look up Bach's Partita No.2 in C Minor BWV 826 - Andante.

Answer (score 0):

Scott Joplin's later works are a perfect showcase of syncopation in classical music. Some of the pieces I would mainly look to are:

The Silver Swan

https://imslp.eu/files/imglnks/euimg/0/05/IMSLP100014-PMLP205389-Joplin_-_Silver_Swan_Rag_(piano).pdf

Paragon Rag

http://vmirror.imslp.org/files/imglnks/usimg/5/5a/IMSLP808354-PMLP13287-Paragon_Rag-Edited.pdf

Heliotrope Bouquet

https://www.ragsrag.com/vp/vp_heliotropebouquet.pdf

Eugina

http://vmirror.imslp.org/files/imglnks/usimg/8/82/IMSLP808017-PMLP13271-Eugenia-Edited.pdf

Weeping Willow

http://www.ragtimepiano.ca/images/weeping.pdf

Of course Maple Leaf Rag and The Entertainer are also very fine examples of syncopation, their melodies are very well known, and some of his other works I feel are just as good examples if not better.

Comment: Note: I believe many people would consider Joplin's compositions to be jazz or ragtime jazz and not classical. But genre is often a matter of opinion.